# Ran update, restarted laptop, trackpad not working

Tags: grub2, xorg, mouse, touchpad

So I was prompted to update my Lubuntu system and I did. There was various updates and I didn't check what they were, I just trusted the system. After installing, I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then restarted my laptop.

Everything went normal except that my laptop trackpad isn't working at all.. No click response or track response.

After trying some options,I went into Grub and loaded a previous version of Linux and the trackpad IS working in the older version.

- Newer version (not working): 4.15.0-72-generic
- Older version (working): 4.15.0-70-generic

I also tried installing:

```
xserver-xorg-input-libinput
xserver-xorg-input-evdev
xserver-xorg-input-mouse
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

None of these commands worked. Well they worked, but they didn't fix the issue.

I have two questions:

- Can I fix this? (I don't have a mouse but I do have another laptop)
- Is there any way to run default from the older Linux version/ will changes be saved in the older version if I'm running it from Grub advanced settings?

Below are my system details, let me know if you need other details:

> Trackpad: Synaptics TM2985-009
>
> Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
>
> Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-64-generic (x86_64)  -(not sure why this is different to details shown in GRUB, I don't think I quite understand if this is the same thing but this is what I get from "System Profiler and Benchmark)
>
> Processer: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz
>
> Laptop: Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14

Comment: Refer https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798 (fix [a reversion] is currently in -proposed as I recall, but details on solution can be found there for most (if not all) Synaptics trackpads *if* this is your issue)

Answer (score 1):

guiverc has pointed out that this is a bug that is currently being tracked and hopefully rectified: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/185479

The fix below applies certainly to my trackpad, which is **Synaptics TM2985-009**

For anyone experiencing this issue, the above link provides bug information and troubleshooting from bug testers.

User AaronMa (mapengyu) - comment #11 - has provided his own 3rd party PPA that rectified the issue for me.

If you would like to test this PPA, input the following commands into terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapengyu/bionic-oem

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-73-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-73-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-73-generic
```

(note that you should trust developers of PPA content before sudo installing)

As mentioned, this fixed the issue for me, however you may have another option which I have not tested as yet. To see information about this option, please visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

This is apparently an official fix, however like above, I haven't tested this as yet. As soon as I do, I will edit this comment, or feel free to test it yourself and reference your results here.

Comment: Personally I'd follow the advice in comment #13 (try the detail out in the *proposed* repository), as if it doesn't work for you, you can speak up (on the launchpad site) and thus they may look into issues that do get your issue resolved.  Chances are the reversion fix will work for you, but it's far easier to fix now rather than trying to start a new *bug* report in the future that impacts far fewer users.  (*note:  I haven't read all comments; I stopped watching that report ~24 hrs ago*)

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a go. I was pretty intimidated by.. well everything on that page at first.. but on second glance, it doesn't seem so bad. Thank you for the support. I'll update my answer on here if it does fix, just for any other users experiencing this.

Comment: Rather than the PPA (3rd party personal archive, which is also used for testing fixes); the *proposed* channel is what i'd recommend as it's *official* that are in *test* that are expected to be released for everyone.   The following maybe helpful (it's out of date & refers to xenial/16.04 & trusty/14.04 but that shouldn't matter) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed   If it works, feel free to make a comment saying so, plus your TM2985-009 detail, and Thank you for taking the time to help to make Ubuntu better!

Comment: The PPA was successful and has fixed the issue. I'll have a look at the proposed channel at another time... it's been a big day and my brain wasn't ready for troubleshooting. Now I'm curious if downloading a PPA like that one could possible contain malicious software? If you don't have time to answer that, I'll research it myself anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: And to answer my own question: 3rd party ppa's could potentially be malicious. It'll be 'right though.

Comment: @JackWild Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195811/ran-update-restarted-laptop-trackpad-not-working/1195813#1195813) this answer in order to give some informations written *here* in comment?

Comment: @damadam Certainly, I will do it now.